# How to set collation of columns in mysql view?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I explicit set the `collation` of a mysql-view or its columns? I want to explicit set the collation to `collacation=utf8_general_ci` for all text/char/varchar columns.

Pseudo-mysql:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(my_table.some + my_table.more),
        some_field, 
        ...
    FROM
        my_table;
```

Comment: Your query does not look like valid MySQL code.  At the very least, explain why you are adding two numbers/dates and using `CONCAT()` to convert the result to a string.  Using `CONCAT()` with one argument is, shall I say, unorthodox to say the least.

Comment: The create statement does not matter for the focus of this question. I'm simply asking if it's possible to set the collation explicit for view columns.

Comment: I didn't know you could change the collation "on the fly" on a view. Interesting to see if this can be done.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `CONVERT(value USING name)` function to specify the character set and collation of an expression.

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT CONVERT(something USING utf8)
...
```

Comment: Great. Though I had to use `USING utf8`, as `utf8_general_ci` gave: *invalid character set*.

Comment: Hmm, that sets the character set, but not the collation.

Comment: Correct, but interestingly the `show create table` shows the correct characters set afterwards. I could not directly set the collation on the table column due to the message above.

Comment: Maybe it's getting that from the database default, I'm not sure.